# java.util.Objects.isNull vs object == null

Tags: java, java-8, compare

As you know, [`java.util.Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) is

> This class consists of static utility methods for operating on objects.

One of such methods is `Objects.isNull()`.

My understanding is that `Objects.isNull()` would remove the chance of accidentally assigning a null value to object by omitting the second `=`.

However, the API Note states:

> This method exists to be used as a Predicate, filter(Objects::isNull)

Would there be any reason/circumstance for which I should use `object == null` over `Objects.isNull()` in an **if statement**?

Should `Objects.isNull()` be confined to Predicates exclusively?

Comment: there`s also Objects.requireNonNull(T obj); btw

Comment: If all you are worrying is accidental assignment, you can simply use `if(null == variable)` consistently…

Comment: @Holder, what accidental assignment is there to worry about?  This is Java.  You'll get a type error.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Not if `variable` is a `Boolean`.

Comment: @AlexisC, that'd be a concern in a _tiny, tiny_ number of cases: your variable has to be a very specific type, _and_ you have to make a very specific typo, _and_ you can't be using any IDE or compiler analysis that would point that out for you (as almost all IDEs would).  I'm quite comfortable not worrying about that case.

Comment: At work, I have seen many instances of **null==object**. When I enquired, I was told that it was to prevent accidental null assignments. Based on comments and answers here provided, I would be inclined to believe that it is a mater of taste.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

> should use object == null over Objects.isNull() in a if statement?

If you look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Objects.java#Objects.isNull%28java.lang.Object%29) of `IsNull` method,

```
 /* Returns true if the provided reference is null otherwise returns false.*/

 public static boolean isNull(Object obj) {
     return obj == null;
 }
```

It is the same. There is no difference. So you can use it safely.

Comment: Yes, it can be used, but it may interfere with local flow analysis performed by a tool. I.e., with a plain "==", any flow analysis can see that dereference is not good in the then branch, but safe in an else branch. You'll get appropriate errors/warnings or nothing. With the indirection of calling isNull() that knowledge may be lost to the tool.

Comment: There IS a slight performance difference. Java checking for object null reference versus calling a static method will have a difference. And it reads slightly less clearly than just using == that we're all used to.

Comment: Is more semantic use `== null` in `if`, but isNull is great to use on lambda expressions.

Comment: it's surely legitimate, but does not have any benefits over the operators. So if you working in a team, please use things according to their intended purpose.

Answer (score 158):

`Objects.isNull` is intended for use within Java 8 lambda filtering.

It's much easier and clearer to write:

```
.stream().filter(Objects::isNull)
```

than to write:

```
.stream().filter(x -> x == null).
```

Within an `if` statement, however, either will work. The use of `== null` is probably easier to read but in the end it will boil down to a style preference.

Comment: I would disagree on the claim that it is "much easier/clearer to write".  
1. It is not more concise.  
2. It is obviously less expressive, especially for those not familiar with latest Java syntax.  

For me as someone who is not writing Java on daily basis (I write Scala) it feels hallucinatory having a static method which does nothing but checking for null.

This method is just a distruction from fluent code reading without any benifits added.

Comment: @EliGolin your phrasing gave me a good laugh

Comment: @EliGolin While I agree with your readability points, there is also a (very slight) performance benefit to not using Lambda expressions here. That is, the program won't have to define and instantiate a new anonymous method, both of which have (very slight) memory/compute overhead compared to just passing `isNull`. Slight as this overhead is, it adds up over all the Stream expressions in your codebase. For this reason alone, I always default to `isNull` syntax in Streams (_not_ in other contexts like if statements).

Comment: Once the expression becomes even slightly more complex though, yes I would probably switch to a Lambda for readability. E.g., `.map(MyType::getProp).filter(Objects.isNull)` feels kinda awkward compared to just `.filter(x -> x.getProp() == nulll)`. Plus, I think the chained `map`/`filter` calls might actually be slower than the single `filter`. But again, we're talking about a super micro difference, and I've never actually benchmarked it.

Comment: One of the tenants of streams usage I follow is to keep the individual operations within the stream and distinct.   There may be a small time difference between the mapping and the filter however in the 80% (percentages may vary) of cases I'd argue for the added clarity.

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-): This method exists to be used as a Predicate, filter(Objects::isNull)

Comment: "Plus, I think the chained map/filter calls might actually be slower than the single filter"

not really, these operation are chained on a single element. this is the same as x.getProp() == null

Answer (score 17):

Look at the source:

```
public static boolean isNull(Object obj) {
    return obj == null;
}
```

To check for `null` values, you can use:

- `Objects.isNull(myObject)`
- `null == myObject // avoids assigning by typo`
- `myObject == null // risk of typo`

The fact that `Objects.isNull` is meant for `Predicate`s does not prevent you from using it as above.

Comment: What do you mean by risk of typo?

Comment: @AshishLohia by using `=` instead of `==` (wouldn't compile unless it's a nullable `Boolean` wrapper, yo be fair)

Comment: Risk of typo is the issue in C++ not in Java if (myObject = null) will result in the compilation error. You should always use myObject == null over null == myObject.

Comment: @TomasMarik as mentioned in my comment, the risk of typo is limited to nullable `Boolean` wrappers in Java. This is pretty rare indeed (and will give compiler warnings when an assignment to `null` is checked as if it were a condition), but not impossible.

Comment: null == myObject. This tricky way should be avoided; it goes against our natural language when comparing something by reading from left to right.

Comment: @emeraldhieu the term for such expression is `yoda conditions` which go against natural language and yes, should be avoided.

Comment: @shazwashere Hah! Thanks for the term! It's useful for me to show other devs in code review.

Answer (score 13):

> Would there be any reason/circumstance for which I should use object == null over Objects.isNull() in a **if statement**?

Yes, one reason is to keep the code simple. Within **if statement** `object == null` is clear and well known. It can not lead to any misbehavior if for example there is a typo.

> My understanding is that Objects.isNull() would remove the chance of accidentally assigning a null value to object by omitting the second =.

If there is an `if (object = null) {}` with **omitted** `=` it will not compile or it will generate warning in case of `Boolean` object! Actually there is no reason to use `Objects.isNull(object)` over `object == null` within **if statement**. Here are the two variants side by side:

```
if (object == null) {
}

if (Objects.isNull(object)) {
}
```

> Should Objects.isNull() be confined to Predicates exclusively?

It could be said yes, it is confined to Predicates exclusively, although there is no technical hurdle to use the `Objects.isNull()` everywhere.

From the `public static boolean isNull(Object obj)` method's javadoc:

> @apiNoteThis method exists to be used as a java.util.function.Predicate, filter(Objects::isNull)

So if you use the method as **not** a predicate you are actually using a more complex and cumbersome expression compared to the simple `object == null`.

Here is a snippet to compare the benefit of `Objects.isNull(object)`

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", null, "c", null);

// As ready-made predicate
long countNullsWithPredicate = list.stream().filter(Objects::isNull).count();

// Lambda
long countNullsWithLambda = list.stream().filter(object -> object == null).count();

// Reimplement the Objects::isNull predicate
long countNullsWithAnonymous = list.stream().filter(new Predicate<Object>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Object obj) {
        return obj == null;
    }
}).count();
```

Answer (score 6):

Semantically there is no difference but for readability I prefer the following over `whatever == null`:

```
import static java.util.Objects.isNull;

// Other stuff...

if(isNull(whatever)) { 

}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a difference in performance? Someone told me calling the method will result in wasted cpu cycles.