# Is there any benefit to use methods of Objects.java?

Tags: java

I examined methods of Objects.java, but i couldn't find too much useful sides of that methods. For Example the code that will work when i use Objects.isNull :

```
public static boolean isNull(Object obj) {
    return obj == null;
}
```

There are the two ways for checking nullity of two objects :

```
if(o == null)
if(Objects.isNull(o))
```

So there are not so many differences between them. Another example the code that will work i use Objects.toString

```
public static String toString(Object o) {
    return String.valueOf(o);
}
```

When i use it It calls toString of object at background.(With only one difference it writes "null", if the object is null because it uses String.valueOf()

And Objects.equals :

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```

It will makes null check in every check(without knowing it is necessary or not.)

Am i wrong? If i am, why should i use **that methods and other methods** of Objects.java?

**EDIT**

I did not asked this question only for Objects.isNull and Objects.nonNull, i want to know purpose, usability(except for lambdas also) and benefits of Objects class and its methods. But in javadoc is written that only for Objects.isNull and Objects.nonNull have purpose to use with lambdas(as predicate filter(Objects::isNull)). I want to know **others** as well.

Comment: There are some insightful comments here: [java.util.Objects.isNull vs object == null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972859/java-util-objects-isnull-vs-object-null)

Comment: You can use them for method reference like Objects::isNull. Equals method is cleaner when using Objects.equals()

Comment: The docs say "These utilities include null-safe or null-tolerant methods for computing the hash code of an object" so, yes useful if you want generate the hash-code in a null-safe way.

Comment: I think those are mostly intended to be used instead of lambdas with the same functionality, for people who prefer method references.

Comment: Seems to make some sense, in respect to other Data Structure .java files of the same concept - this is the base class of the DSs, and the implementations are the base functionality for Objects.

Comment: Yeah as stated you can use the Method reference since Java 8. But I think the bigger benefit and probably the reason they are used so much is it improves readability and maintainability.

Comment: In case of [`Objects.isNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-) (and few others) documentation states: "*API Note: This method exists to be used as a `Predicate`, `filter(Objects::isNull)`*".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Objects.isNull()`, and the more useful `Objects.nonNull()`, exist for the purpose of being used in lambda expressions. `Objects.toString()` was introduced for null safety (as pointed out by @davidxxx), but is also very useful in lambdas.

For example, `list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).map(Objects::toString)` will give you a `Stream<String>` with the results of calling `toString()` on all the elements in `list` that are not null.

`Objects.equals()` is useful precisely when you know that the objects you're comparing might be null, as it saves you some typing.

Comment: It makes sense for me. Well, is it useful to use them except lambdas?

Comment: Of the ones you mentioned, only `Objects.equals()`, and possibly `Objects.toString()` (if you're happy with `null` becoming `"null"`). [Check out the others](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html), though; some of them might come in handy. For example, `Objects.requireNonNull()` is nice if you want to protect early against accidental null values and provide a clearer error message.

Comment: "Objects.toString() and Objects.isNull() (and the more useful Objects.nonNull()) exist for the purpose of being used in lambda expressions." For `Objects.toString()` not really as it was already existed in Java 7 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString(java.lang.Object))

Comment: @Alexander That's not valid method reference syntax.

Comment: @shmosel Ahhh it only works for Collectors.toList(), and even then it only works because it's a method (needs () to be called) that returns a lambda D:

Comment: It returns a Collector.

Comment: @davidxxx: Good point; I edited that in.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be asking 3 separate questions, so I'll address them separately:

1. `isNull()` and its companion `nonNull()` were added in Java 8 to be used as method references, similarly to `Integer.sum()` and `Boolean.logicalOr()`. For example:

   ```
   // Print only non-null elements
   list.stream()
       .filter(Objects::nonNull)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
   ```
2. I don't see any advantage in calling `Objects.toString()` over `String.valueOf()`. Maybe it was included for uniformity with the other null-safe helpers.
3. If you know the objects are non-null, go ahead and use `Object.equals()`. `Objects.equals()` is meant to be used when they might both be null.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases some of these methods don't bring a "great" value and you can suitably ignore them.

1) But as you manipulate classes that miss some checks (check `null` to prevent `NullPointerException`) or "optimization" (check first reference equality in `equals()` for example) , using these `Objects` methods allow to not be hurt by these and so to
keep your client code robust without writing directly all these checks.

2) Another interesting use is for lambda body as you want to use a method reference

3) At last, it allows to make homogeneous the way to perform these very common processings.

These 3 processing rely on 3 different ways :

```
String.valueOf(o);
if(o == null){...} 
a.equals(b);
```

While these rely on a single way : utility methods defined in `Objects`.

```
Objects.toString(o);
if(Objects.isNull(o)){...}
if(Objects.equals(a, b)){...}
```

Comment: Should i use them for readability concerns for example: if(Objects.isNull(o)) is seems more readible than if(o == null)

Comment: It makes more "Object". For null checking it is a taste question I think.