# How to get warning for "object == null" in Java in Intellji?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[java.util.Objects.isNull vs object == null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972859/java-util-objects-isnull-vs-object-null/37972924)

Using java 8.
seems Objects.isNull() is the recommended way,
is there a way to get warning if we write like this "object == null" ?

Thanks !

Comment: [Create a custom inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-custom-inspections.html)

Comment: `isNull` is primarily there to be used as a lambda, as described in the question you linked. There's no "recommendation" to use it instead of `== null`.

Comment: Think of it this way: the only way that `if (foo = null)` even compiles is if `foo` is specifically a `Boolean` and in that case it will *always* throw a `NullPointerException`. So I don't think it's very likely that a typo like that ever goes unnoticed.

Comment: Thanks for guys above, someone in the team has a very strong opinion, otherwise cannot pass code review.

Comment: I think your starting point is wrong. The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-) is quite clear about recommending how to use this: `This method exists to be used as a Predicate, filter(Objects::isNull)`

Answer (score 0):

In the code sample as follows:

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", null, null);
    boolean b = list.stream().anyMatch(str -> str == null);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA will suggest you a fix to change the lambda with method reference,
and you will have:

```
boolean b = list.stream().anyMatch(Objects::isNull);
```

instead.

The inspection that is responsible for the fix is ***Java | Java language level migration aids | Java 8 | Lambda can be replaced with method reference***.